# How to focus an input in React via refs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, react-ref

I'm using React JS and have faced a problem.

I have a component on the page which has some `inputs`. When user clicks on any `input` a new block should be created below and the same `input` has to be focused at the same time.

Everything worked until I've created a show logic:

```
const readyBlock = isTouched ? <ViewModule textInput={textInput}/> : null;
```

After that I get ×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null

Below is my Main component where everything on the page happens.

```
const Sales = () => {
    const [isTouched, setIsTouched] = useState(false);
    const textInput = useRef(null);


    function handleInput() {
        setIsTouched(true);

        textInput.current.focus();
    }

    const readyBlock = isTouched ? <ViewModule textInput={textInput}/> : null;
    return (
        <main className="sales-page">
            <div className="main__title">
                <h2 className="main__heading">Bonuses</h2>
            </div>
            <div className="content-container">
                <UploadForm>
                    <FileUploadInput 
                        handleChange={handleInput}
                        placeholder="Header"/>
                    <FileUploadTextArea placeholder="Descr"/>
                </UploadForm>
            </div>
            <div className="ready-container ">
                {readyBlock}
            </div>
        </main>
    )
}

const ViewModule = ({textInput}) => {
    return (
        <UploadForm classNames="textarea-written">
            <FileUploadInput 
                ref={textInput}
                placeholder="Заголовок"/>
            <FileUploadTextArea placeholder="Descr"/>
            <div className="btn-container">
                <Btn classNames="cancel-btn">Cancel</Btn>
                <Btn>Save</Btn>
            </div>
        </UploadForm>
    )
}
```

Below is an input component:

```
const FileUploadInput = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    
    return (
        <div className="text-input-wrapper">
            <input
                ref={ref} 
                type="text" 
                id="file-text-input" 
                name="file__upload-title" 
                placeholder={props.placeholder}
                onClick={props.handleChange} />
        </div>
    )
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to focus the ViewModule component when its added.
The problem is that the Ref textInput is not assigned to any component before the ViewModule is added to the DOM tree. You would have to first add the ViewModule to the DOM tree on state change and then later in a useEffect hook you will find the textInput Ref properly assigned.

```
function handleInput() {
   setIsTouched(true);
}

useEffect(() => {
   if (textInput.current === null) return
   if (isTouched) textInput.current.focus();
}, [isTouched])
```

Also you should pass the textInput Ref to ViewModule using React.forwardRef as you did for FileUploadInput.

```
const ViewModule = React.forwardRef((ref) => {...});
```

And use it like this.

```
const readyBlock = isTouched ? <ViewModule ref={textInput}/> : null;
```